# Symfony 2: Set field as read only after first save

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony 2 entity. When I create a new record, I must fill all the values using a form, but after saving it, one of the values, $amount shouldn't be updatable when I update the others members.

How can I accomplish this? It's possible to mark a form member as a read-only, in runtime?

Comment: On the edition route, you can create a second `EntityType` which will not add the `amount` property. To process the validation, you can use [validation groups](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the `validation_groups` and `name` options when creating your form, you can change the form.
The `name` attribute sets the form creation, and the `validation_groups` takes care of the validation.
For example, in the create/new method of your controller;

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    // Instantiate new Foo object
    $client = new Foo();

    // create the form (setting validation group)
    $form = $this->formFactory->create('foo', $foo, array(
        'name' => 'create',
        'validation_groups' => array('create')
            )
    );

    // form has been submitted...
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        // submits the form
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // do validation
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // do whatever
        }
    }

    // either GET or validation failed, so show the form
    return $this->template->renderResponse('FooBundle:foo:add.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'foo' => $foo
    ));
}
```

And in the edit/update function of your controller;

```
public function updateAction($id, Request $request)
{
    // Instantiate Client object
    $client = new Foo($id);

    // create the form (setting validation group)
    $form = $this->formFactory->create('foo', $foo, array(
        'name' => 'update',
        'validation_groups' => array('update')
    ));

    // form has been submitted...
    if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
        // submits the form
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        // do validation
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // do whatever
        }
    }

    // either GET or validation failed, so show the form
    return $this->template->renderResponse('FooBundle:foo/edit:index.html.twig', array(
                'form' => $form->createView(),
                'foo' => $foo
    ));
}
```

And your Form Type will look something like;

```
class FooType extends BaseAbstractType
{
    protected $options = array(
        'data_class' => 'FooBundle\Model\Foo',
        'name'       => 'foo',
    );

    private $roleManager;

    public function __construct($mergeOptions = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($mergeOptions);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $this->$options['name']($builder, $options);
    }

    private function create(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ID
        $builder->add('Id', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'ID',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Format: 2 alphanumeric (e.g. A1)'
            )
        ));

        // Name - only show on create
        $builder->add('Name', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Your name'
            )
        ));

        // add the submit form button
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Save'
        ));
    }

    private function update(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // ID
        $builder->add('Id', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'ID',
            'attr' => array(
                'placeholder' => 'Format: 2 alphanumeric (e.g. A1)',
            )
        ));

        // Name - just for show
        $builder->add('Name', 'text', array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => 'Name',
            'attr' => array(
                'readonly' => 'true' // stops it being editable
            )
        ));

        // add the submit form button
        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Save'
        ));
    }
}
```

P.S. All my classes are declared as services, so how you call create forms/views/etc may be different.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't working for me. I've declared my form classes as services, but I'm unable to call to $this->formFactory->create from the controller (formFactory doesn't exist). If I call to $this->createForm, it doesn't work because I pass the 'name' value in the array, it throws an exception saying that this is an incorrect value for the array... What I'm doing wrong? Can this problem be because I have the SonataAdminBundle installed?

Comment: @mHouses have you declared use Symfony\Component\Form\FormFactoryInterface; in your controller (which for me is also a service) and DI it to the formFactory attribute?